# ajax tab container CSS not displayed properly

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using AJAX Tab Container as below. I have a CSS to format the tab panel headers. I have used images there (light blue colored). Now I want 2 things:
1. I wanna get rid of the dotted box
2. I want the selected tab to become light blue in color. (I know that the light blue image is present in the background. Its just that its not coming on the selected tab)

[image: tab container]

```
 <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
                    CssClass="ajax__tab_lightblue-theme">
                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="My Profile" ID="tbpnlMyProfile">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            My Profile</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <table style="width: 100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="colwid colht">
                                         <strong><a href="#" id="lnkEditMyInfo" class="small-heading">Edit My Info</a>
                                        </strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblFirstNameMyProfile" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>



.ajax__tab_lightblue-theme .ajax__tab_header 
{
font-family:arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;
font-size:small;
border-bottom:solid 5px #c2e0fd;
}
.ajax__tab_lightblue-theme .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_outer 
{
background-image:url('Images1/lightblue.jpg') #d8d8d8 repeat-x;
margin:0px 0.16em 0px 0px;
padding:1px 0px 1px 0px;
vertical-align:bottom;
border:solid 1px #a3a3a3;
border-bottom-width:0px;
}
.ajax__tab_lightblue-theme .ajax__tab_header .ajax__tab_tab
{    
color:#000;
padding:0.35em 0.75em;    
margin-right:0.01em;
}
.ajax__tab_lightblue-theme .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_outer 
{
background-image: url('Images1/lightblue.jpg') #bfdaff repeat-x left -1300px;
}
.ajax__tab_lightblue-theme .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_tab 
 {
color:#000;
}
.ajax__tab_lightblue-theme .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_outer
{
background-image:url('Images1/lightblue.jpg') #ffffff repeat-x left -1400px;
}
    .ajax__tab_lightblue-theme .ajax__tab_body 
{
font-family:verdana,tahoma,helvetica;
font-size:10pt;
padding:0.25em 0.5em;
background-color:#ffffff;    
border:solid 1px #808080;
border-top-width:0px;
 }
```

Comment: I have provided an answer, however you should include the CSS for your address book tab as I can only guess without seeing the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The dotted box comes from outline, this is a browser specific feature which all browsers render differently. You can disable it by adding the style `outline:none;`. With that said I wouldn't recommend it as people with disabilities rely on this when tabing through websites.

As for the space under the address book tab. This is most likely some unwanted padding or margin. Set the margin and padding for address book to `padding:0;` and `margin:0;` and see what happens.

**ANSWER TO YOUR COMMENT:**

Well I don't see Markup for "My Profile" and "Address Book". So I am assuming this is some "out of the box" ASP.NET stuff. But what you would need to add it to is the "My Profile" and "Address Book" links.

**So assuming your generated HTML is something like this:**

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="">My Profile</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Address Book</a></li>
</ul>
```

**You would add a class to your element like this:** *(notice the class tabednav)*

```
<ul class="tabednav">
   <li><a href="">My Profile</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Address Book</a></li>
</ul>
```

**And then add CSS to your stylesheet:**

```
.tabednav li a {outline:none;}
```

Comment: where exactly in this CSS should I add outline:none; ?

Comment: I added an answer to your comment, hopefully it is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the AjaxToolKit, set the following in your CSS.

```
/*Remove the border from the TabStrip*/
.ajax__tab_lightblue-theme .ajax__tab_header 
{
    border-bottom:none;
}

/*Add a border to the active tab*/
.ajax__tab_lightblue-theme .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_outer
{
    border:solid 5px #c2e0fd;
}
```